# How to include dynamic time?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, numpy, pandas

I am trying to pull the logs with respect to time slots. The program below runs very fine when no. of hours are given and the logs in that range gets extracted.

But now I also what to include Start and end to be dynamically given. i.e. say between `8 am to 8pm` or `6am to 8am` and so on.

How do I get that? Any edit in the current program will also do or a separate program will also do.

Input: Mini Version of [INPUT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/varv1lyb5uskexh/dart_small.csv?dl=0)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,time
import numpy as np

fn = r'00_Dart.csv'
cols = ['UserID','StartTime','StopTime', 'gps1', 'gps2']
df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime

# 'start' and 'end' for the reporting DF: `r`
# which will contain equal intervals (1 hour in this case)
start = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime.min(), unit='s').date()
end = pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime.max(), unit='s').date() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# building reporting DF: `r`
freq = '1H'  # 1 Hour frequency
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
r['start'] = (r.index - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds().astype(np.int64)

# 1 hour in seconds, minus one second (so that we will not count it twice)
interval = 60*60 - 1

r['LogCount'] = 0
r['UniqueIDCount'] = 0

for i, row in r.iterrows():
        # intervals overlap test
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test
        # i've slightly simplified the calculations of m and d
        # by getting rid of division by 2,
        # because it can be done eliminating common terms
    u = df[np.abs(df.m - 2*row.start - interval) < df.d + interval].UserID
    r.ix[i, ['LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount']] = [len(u), u.nunique()]

r['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.date
r['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.weekday_name.str[:3]
r['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.time
r['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start + interval + 1, unit='s').dt.time

#r.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
#print(r[r.LogCount > 0])
#print (r['StartTime'], r['EndTime'], r['Day'], r['LogCount'], r['UniqueIDCount'])

rout =  r[['Date', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Day', 'LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount'] ]
#print rout
rout.to_csv('one_hour.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

**Edit:**

In Simple words, I should be able to give `StartTime` and `EndTIme` in the program. The code below is very much close to what I am trying to do. But how convert this to pandas.

```
from datetime import datetime,time

start = time(8,0,0)
end =   time(20,0,0)

with open('USC28days_0_20', 'r') as infile, open('USC28days_0_20_time','w') as outfile:
    for row in infile:
        col = row.split()
        t1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(col[2])).time()
        t2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(col[3])).time()
        print (t1 >= start and t2 <= end)
```

**Edit Two:** Working answer in Pandas

Taking a Part from the @MaxU's answer from selected answer. The below code strips the required group of logs between the given `StartTime` and `StopTime`

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,time
import numpy as np

fn = r'00_Dart.csv'
cols = ['UserID','StartTime','StopTime', 'gps1', 'gps2']

df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

#df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
#df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime

# filter input data set ... 
start_hour = 8
end_hour = 9
df = df[(pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime, unit='s').dt.hour >= start_hour) & (pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime, unit='s').dt.hour <= end_hour)]

print df

df.to_csv('time_hour.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

**But:** If there was a possibility to have control on minutes and seconds also would be great solution.

At present this also strips the logs which have the hour of `StopTime` but also the minutes and seconds until the next hour.

Something like

```
start_hour = 8:0:0
end_hour = 9:0:0 - 1 # -1 to get the logs until 8:59:59
```

But this gives me an error

Comment: can you post a sample input and desired output data sets?

Comment: @MaxU I made a edit in question and included a mini version of full dataset

Comment: could you please explain how do you want to count? Do you want to exclude / ignore all rows where the timestamp is not in the specified hour-range?

Comment: @MaxU I did already .. But again the program here helps me separate data with given count of hours. i.e. every hr or 2 hrs or 12 hrs n so on. But now I want to give the time i.e. from 6 am to 8am  or 8 to 20 hrs (8 am to 8pm) and so on.

Comment: `I should be able to give StartTime and EndTIme` - this part is clear. :) What are you going to do with those variables then? Do you want to build report for one day 8am - 6pm or do you want to build report for __all__ days excluding _non-working_ hours?

Comment: The data is some kind.of logs.  So my intension is to separate the logs in those time series.  Per day and over all will also do.  One case with respect to date and another case irrespective of date.  Two outputs would be great.  Has to do nothing with holidays or weekends.. Every day is counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,time
import numpy as np

fn = r'D:\data\gDrive\data\.stack.overflow\2016-07\dart_small.csv'
cols = ['UserID','StartTime','StopTime', 'gps1', 'gps2']

df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

df['m'] = df.StopTime + df.StartTime
df['d'] = df.StopTime - df.StartTime

# filter input data set ... 
start_hour = 8
end_hour = 20
df = df[(pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime, unit='s').dt.hour >= 8) & (pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime, unit='s').dt.hour <= 20)]


# 'start' and 'end' for the reporting DF: `r`
# which will contain equal intervals (1 hour in this case)
start = pd.to_datetime(df.StartTime.min(), unit='s').date()
end = pd.to_datetime(df.StopTime.max(), unit='s').date() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# building reporting DF: `r`
freq = '1H'  # 1 Hour frequency
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
r = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
r = r[(r.index.hour >= start_hour) & (r.index.hour <= end_hour)]
r['start'] = (r.index - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds().astype(np.int64)

# 1 hour in seconds, minus one second (so that we will not count it twice)
interval = 60*60 - 1

r['LogCount'] = 0
r['UniqueIDCount'] = 0

for i, row in r.iterrows():
        # intervals overlap test
        # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Overlap_test
        # i've slightly simplified the calculations of m and d
        # by getting rid of division by 2,
        # because it can be done eliminating common terms
    u = df[np.abs(df.m - 2*row.start - interval) < df.d + interval].UserID
    r.ix[i, ['LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount']] = [len(u), u.nunique()]

r['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.date
r['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.weekday_name.str[:3]
r['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start, unit='s').dt.time
r['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(r.start + interval + 1, unit='s').dt.time

#r.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
#print(r[r.LogCount > 0])
#print (r['StartTime'], r['EndTime'], r['Day'], r['LogCount'], r['UniqueIDCount'])

rout =  r[['Date', 'StartTime', 'EndTime', 'Day', 'LogCount', 'UniqueIDCount'] ]
#print rout
```

**OLD answer:**

```
from_time = '08:00'
to_time = '18:00'
rout.between_time(from_time, to_time).to_csv('one_hour.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: THanks! This looks pretty much close. But how do I parse the `StartTime & EndTime` to be considered in `from_time & to_time` ? This looks workable for irrespective of Date.

Comment: @SitzBlogz, sorry, i'm not quite getting you, could you make a small example?

Comment: This looks correct.. No problem at all..  But I am confused on how to put the inputs into them so that we can have a output.. In short how do I parse the input

Comment: @SitzBlogz, my idea was to filter the output / reporting DF, not the input one

Comment: Oh oh..  please will it be possible with input.. Coz output are already refined..

Comment: I did include a edit section with a code that works with a different dataset. But I am not able to put it in Pandas.

Comment: I am finding the new answer confusing to understand. We do not need old program at all.  :(

Comment: Please Check Edit Two in question. I did get what I was looking for. Thanks of-course a little more tail to the answer is remaining.