# df.to_csv structuring the output

Tags: python, date, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write an output to a `csv` but I am getting different format.

What do I change for getting a clean output.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('one_hour.csv')
df.columns = ['date', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'day', 'count', 'unique']

count_med = df.groupby(['date'])[['count']].median()
unique_med = df.groupby(['date'])[['unique']].median()
date_count = df['date'].nunique()
#print count_med
#print unique_med

cols = ['date_count', 'count_med', 'unique_med']
outf = pd.DataFrame([[date_count, count_med, unique_med]], columns = cols)
outf.to_csv('date_med.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Input: only few rows from the huge data file.

```
2004-01-05,21:00:00,22:00:00,Mon,16553,783
2004-01-05,22:00:00,23:00:00,Mon,18944,790
2004-01-05,23:00:00,00:00:00,Mon,17534,750
2004-01-06,00:00:00,01:00:00,Tue,17262,747
2004-01-06,01:00:00,02:00:00,Tue,19072,777
2004-01-06,02:00:00,03:00:00,Tue,18275,785
2004-01-06,03:00:00,04:00:00,Tue,13589,757
2004-01-06,04:00:00,05:00:00,Tue,16053,735
2004-01-06,05:00:00,06:00:00,Tue,11440,636
```

Output

```
63,"              count
date               
2004-01-05  10766.0
2004-01-06  11530.0
2004-01-07  11270.0
2004-01-08  14819.5
2004-01-09  12933.5
2004-01-10  10088.0
2004-01-11  10923.0
2004-02-03  14760.5
...             ...
2004-02-07  10131.5
2004-02-08  11184.0

[63 rows x 1 columns]","            unique
date              
2004-01-05   633.0
2004-01-06   741.0
2004-01-07   752.5
2004-02-03   779.5
...            ...
2004-02-07   643.5

[63 rows x 1 columns]"
```

But the expected output is not supposed to be like this.

Expected Output: Rounded off values along with the date

```
2004-01-05,10766,633 
2004-01-06,11530,741
2004-01-07,11270,752
```

Comment: please post a sample input data set in the original CSV format and desired output / data set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
cols = ['date', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'day', 'count', 'unique']

df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=cols)

df.groupby(['date'])[['count','unique']].agg({'count':'median','unique':'median'}).round().to_csv('d:/temp/out.csv', header=None)
```

out.csv:

```
2004-01-05,764,17044.0
2004-01-06,757,17262.0
```

Comment: need rounded off values

Comment: @SitzBlogz, i've added `.round()`

Comment: Great this works wonderful but I still have float values :( can I change them to integer ?

Comment: Yes I checked the stackpoints and you have less than him so chose your ans thank you so much again ..

Comment: If you happen to have a little time It would be great to get some help with this one too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344487/how-to-include-dynamic-time

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""2004-01-05,21:00:00,22:00:00,Mon,16553,783
2004-01-05,22:00:00,23:00:00,Mon,18944,790
2004-01-05,23:00:00,00:00:00,Mon,17534,750
2004-01-06,00:00:00,01:00:00,Tue,17262,747
2004-01-06,01:00:00,02:00:00,Tue,19072,777
2004-01-06,02:00:00,03:00:00,Tue,18275,785
2004-01-06,03:00:00,04:00:00,Tue,13589,757
2004-01-06,04:00:00,05:00:00,Tue,16053,735
2004-01-06,05:00:00,06:00:00,Tue,11440,636"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[0], names=['date', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'day', 'count', 'unique'])
print (df)

outf = df.groupby('date')['count', 'unique'].median().round().astype(int)
print (outf)
            count  unique
date                     
2004-01-05  17534     783
2004-01-06  16658     752


outf.to_csv('date_med.csv', header=False)
```

**Timings**:

```
In [20]: %timeit df.groupby('date')['count', 'unique'].median().round().astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.67 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit df.groupby(['date'])[['count','unique']].agg({'count':'median','unique':'median'}).round().astype(int)
The slowest run took 4.44 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 3.64 ms per loop
```

Comment: I get this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "date_median.py", line 15, in <module>
    outf = pd.DataFrame({'date_count': date_count, 'count_med': count_med, 'unique_med': unique_med}).reset_index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5231, in _arrays_to_mgr
    index = extract_index(arrays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5270, in extract_index
    raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Comment: sorry, I edit answer. Now it works nice, there are also convert float to int.

Comment: It is up to you. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @MaxU has low stackpoints so let me help him gain a little more.

Comment: If you happen to have a little time It would be great to get some help with this one too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344487/how-to-include-dynamic-time

Comment: Ok, no problem. Only my solution is faster, so you can use it.

Comment: I did check its really cool solution ... Best learning today :)